# Uploadcare widget with multiple file picker

Tags: javascript, file-upload, uploadcare

I have an Uploadcare widget with multiple upload enabled. When I call the function `uploadcare.Widget("[role=uploadcare-uploader]")`, it raises an exception

My input:

```
<input type="hidden" 
       id="uploadcare-uploader"
       data-multiple 
       data-images-only
       data-multiple-max="15"
       role="uploadcare-uploader" 
       name="my_file" />
```

Also, how to get UUIDs of the images uploaded by a user in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work, as you trying to initialise single file widget when you should have used multiple one. Try this:

```
var multipleWidget = uploadcare.MultipleWidget("[role=uploadcare-uploader]");
```

As for getting UUIDs:

```
$ = uploadcare.jQuery; // skip this if you already have jQuery on the page
multipleWidget.onChange(function(group) {
  if (group) {
    group; // group object
    group.files(); // array of file objects
    $.when.apply(null, group.files()).then(function() {
      arguments; // array of individual file infos
      $.each(arguments, function() {
        console.log(this.cdnUrl); // URL of uploaded file
        console.log(this.uuid);   // UUID of uploaded file
      });
    });
  }
});
```

You can find more details in the [docs](https://uploadcare.com/documentation/javascript_api/#widget)